# How can I change VS Code explorer font-size only?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

I want only change VSCode explorer section fontsize, Is there a way to only change font size in the red section in picture?

I tried to zoom, but zoom change all font-size in vscode, I want only change font size in the red section in picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no built-in way to do this.

Unless you use something like [`be5invis.vscode-custom-css`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=be5invis.vscode-custom-css) (note its caveats in its readme) <sup><sub>(I have no affiliation with this extension)</sub></sup>, in which case you can use the `Developer: Toggle Developer Tools` to inspect the DOM tree (and you may be interested in the `explorer-folders-view` CSS class).